# Ignore latex macros when replacing characters with regex

Tags: regex, perl, latex

I have a file that I need to convert out of a custom codepage.  The file has things like this:

```
foo bar baz \bazfoo \barfoo foo bar \foobar
```

I want to replace foo with bar, except when foo occurs as part of a LaTeX macro, such as \bazfoo, \barfoo, and \foobar

In other words, `s/foo/bar/`, but  \bazfoo must remain \bazfoo. Is there a way to do this using lookead operators?

Answer (score 4):

Can require that a word with the pattern not begin with `\`, using the negated character class

```
s{(?: ^|\s ) (?: [^\\\s]\S* )? \K foo}{XXX}gx
```

The `foo` may also come at the beginning of the string, or a word, thus the alternation `^|\s` and `[^\\\s]\S*` is optional. The `\` need be escaped in the character class or it would itself escape the `]`.

The `\K` drops all matches up to that point, so we don't have to capture them and put them back.

The negative lookbehind doesn't allow variable-length patterns, what is a problem here.

Test, with an addition to your test string

```
perl -wE'$_=q(foo bar somefoo \bazfoo \barfoo foo bar \foobar); say; 
    s{(?: ^|\s ) (?: [^\\\s]\S* )? \K foo}{XXX}gx; say'
```

prints

```
foo bar somefoo \bazfoo \barfoo foo bar \foobar
XXX bar someXXX \bazfoo \barfoo XXX bar \foobar
```

Note that your test string doesn't include the case when `foo` is inside of a word but still need be replaced, like `somefoo`.  I added it above

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle `foo` appearing twice in one word.

Comment: Fixed another bug.

Comment: @ikegami It doesn't handle `foo` twice, indeed, thanks for noting it, and thank you for the space-space fix. (The last one wasn't a bug -- there's always been a test for that case, `somefoo`.  But it's cleaner this way.)

Comment: You had a test case for "... somefoo" but not for "somefoo". It didn't work for the latter

Comment: @ikegami Heh, yes, indeed. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

While there is already a fascinating solution by zdim, I still want to share my version.

I also had issues because of the variable length lookbehind.

So my solution is to "tokenize" the string meaning: Pick out each "word" and replace only in those which are not starting with \.

```
perl -e '
  $_=q(foo bar baz \bazfoo \barfoo foo bar \foobar);
  s/(\S+)/                  # pick the word
    $word=$1;               # save it
    if ($word!~m#^\\#) {    # test for LaTeX
      $word=~s#foo#bar#g;   # otherwise replace
    }
    $word                   # the result
  /gex;                     # globally, execute and eXtended for comments
  print $_;
'
```

Unfortunately this requires the "e"(-xecute) flag to be used.

**Update:** According to @Alex (see comment below) »This solution won't find {\foo}, which is valid LaTeX syntax.«.

So if required change the if-statement line above to `if ($word!~m#^\\|^\{\\.*\}$#) {`.

Comment: That becomes much simpler in 5.14 with the addition of `/r`: `s{(\S+)}{ $1 =~ /^\\/ ? $1 : $1 =~ s/foo/bar/gr }eg`

Comment: Nothing wrong with `/e` flag when it's needed. (The efficiency takes a hit since the regex engine is started once or twice more but that most often does not matter, and it does simplify the regex.)

Comment: Yeah, no problem with /e. s/foo/bar/ is semantically the same as s/foo/"bar"/e and I would guess them to be equally fast.

Comment: This solution won't find {\foo}, which is valid LaTeX syntax.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Alex. I never used LaTeX and thus was just writing my RE for the question asked. I think it wouldn't be an issue to change the if-statement to `if ($word!~m#^\\|^\{\\.*\}$#)`

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to handle one `foo` per word:

```
s/ (?: ^ | \s++ ) (?: [^\\\s]\S* )? \K foo /bar/gx
```

If you just need to handle multiple `foo` per word:

```
s{ (?: ^ | \s++ ) \K ( [^\\\s]\S* ) }{ $1 =~ s/foo/bar/rg }egx
```

These are fixed and optimized versions of the solutions in the earlier answers. (Fixes but not optimisations also made to the earlier answers.)

Answer (score 0):

if we're sure any Latex token character will never be word char. and your data in 'd', simply:

```
sed -E 's/(^|\s)(\w*)foo/\1\2bar/g' d
perl -pe 's/(^|\s)(?:\w*)foo/$1bar/g' d
```